# Stop fs.createWriteStream creating writeable stream when file is deleted

Tags: javascript, node.js

Folks: I'm creating an Angular/Node app, where users download files via selecting a related thumbnail.

- As files download, a small list is shown with the download progress - using [status-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/status-bar).
- When the file is downloaded a success message is shown.
- Each item in the list has a delete button which removes the files when clicked. All of this works fine.

**Question**: Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301438/node-js-detecting-a-file-opened-with-fs-createwritestream-becoming-deleted) - when the delete button is clicked, the idea is to stop the download -  this is why I thought I'd just delete file.

However, I'm using `fs.createWriteStream` and when the file is deleted, the stream appears to continue, regardless of the file not being there.  This then causes the `file.on('finish', function() {` state to kick in and show the success message.

To tackle this, I check to see if the file path exists when the `finish` state kicks in so to display the success message correctly. This feels pretty hacky, especially when there's large files downloading.

Is there a way to cancel the stream from progressing when the file is deleted?

Comment: I think you can call file.end( optionalCallback );

Comment: @Molda - didn't seem to work.. Is there a way to destroy the stream?

Comment: Are you downloading by requesting through get method? I mean to say,  are you creating the write stream by doing something like this? `http.get(options, function(res) { res.on('data', function(data) {file.write(data);}).on('end', function() {file.end();});`

Comment: @years_of_no_light - yes, just like that - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment 'yes, just like that', I have one question. You are obviously creating the file in client system, and writing in streams. How are you doing it from browser? Are you using any API that gives you access of node's core module in browser? Like [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Having said that, if my understanding is correct, you can achieve that in the following way

```
var http = require("http"),
        fs = require("fs"),
        stream = require("stream"),
        util = require("util"),
        abortStream=false,  // When user click on delete, update this flag to true
        ws,
        Transform;

ws = fs.createWriteStream('./op.jpg');

// Transform streams  read input, process data [n times], output processed data
// readStream ---pipe---> transformStream1 ---pipe---> ...transformStreamn ---pipe---> outputStream
// @api https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform
// @exmpl https://strongloop.com/strongblog/practical-examples-of-the-new-node-js-streams-api/ 
Transform = stream.Transform || require("readable-stream").Transform;

function InterruptedStream(options){
    if(!(this instanceof InterruptedStream)){
        return new InterruptedStream;
    }

    Transform.call(this, options);
}

util.inherits(InterruptedStream, Transform);

InterruptedStream.prototype._transform = function (chunkdata, encoding, done) {
    // This is just for illustration, giving you the idea
    // Do not hard code the condition here.
    // Suggested to give the condition during constructor call, may be
    if(abortStream===true){
        // Take care of this part.
        // Your logic might try to write in the stream after it is closed.
        // You can catch the exception but before that try not to write in the first place
        this.end(); // Stops the stream
    }
    this.push(chunkdata, encoding);
  done();
};


var is=new InterruptedStream();
is.pipe(ws);

// Download large file
http.get("http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1920x1200/2011/Space_Huge_explosion_031412_.jpg", function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            is.write(data);
            // Simulates click on delete button
            setTimeout(function(){
                abortStream=false;
                res.destroy();
                // Delete the file, I think you have the logic in place
            }, 2000);
        }).on('end', function() {
                console.log("end");
        });
    });
```

The above code snippet gives rough idea how its to be done. You can just copy paste it, run (it will work) and make changes.

If we are not on same page please let me know, Ill try to rectify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can emit an event when your file is deleted and capture that event in

```
var wt = fs.createWriteStream();
wt.on('eventName',function(){
                wt.emit('close');                                     
})
```

this will close your writableStream.

and delete event should be fired from client side.